# Accesing real-world inclination and orientation of mobile device via react-native

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I would like to access the inclination of the mobile device. Is there a toole or native methode to do so?

The aim is to get the current position of the device. Including geo-location, orientation in degree and inclination of the device.

The react-native Geolocation API gives me the current location. If understood correctly via NativeEventEmitter I can access the orientation.
But does it also let me access the inclination (~data of the inbuild compass) or is there a recommended way to access it in react-native?

I would like to get some recommendation for tools. Thankful for guides but not necessary. Usually a hint on where to look is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two great repositories. https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors is very complete and still is maintained, https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-heading is also another repository. It has simpler syntax but it seems that it no longer is maintained.

Comment: The gyroscope seems to be exactly what I need.
Thank you very much :-)